# What's the "Tower of Darkness" in the Rubaiyat referring to?

Tags: meaning, persian-language, the-rubaiyat, omar-khayyam, edward-fitzgerald

Stanza 26: (from the English version by FitzGerald)

> A Muezzin from the Tower of Darkness cries
>   "Fools! Your reward is neither Here nor There!"

What's the "Tower of Darkness" referred to?

I'm assuming the tower part is a [minaret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minaret), but beyond that I have no clue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**TL;DR**: FitzGerald made it up. Why? We don't know.

---

As I expected, the translations of Rubaiyat are all over the place when it comes to sticking to the *original* text. First, I came across [an analysis or FitzGerald's translation](http://www.bobforrestweb.co.uk/The_Rubaiyat/verse_by_verse_notes.htm), which says the following:

> The sense here is presumably one of a disembodied Voice calling from the Great Unknown.

**But**, this analysis also provides two different translations of the same rubai<sup>1</sup>, by Edward Heron-Allen:

> Some are immersed in contemplation of doctrine and faith,
>   Others stand stupefied between doubt and certainty,
>   Suddenly a Muezzin from his lurking place, cries out
>   “O Fools! The Road is neither here nor there.”

and Arthur J. Arberry:

> Some people are meditating upon doctrine and faith,
>   one group are bewildered about doubt and certainty;
>   suddenly a proclamation emerges from a hiding-place –
>   ‘O ignorant ones, the way is neither that nor this.’

The second translator notes that the muezzin (and, I guess, the tower too) does not appear in the original script. This is backed by the Russian translations that I dug up: out of 16 (!) translations of the same verse, only one (!) mentions a tower.

All and all, the tower appears to be a creation of FitzGerald. The forums I visited so far seem to agree that what FitzGerald did is more of a *rendition* than a translation.

Here's what Edward Heron-Allen has to say about this verse:

> Masterly as is this paraphrase, the original is even more interesting. It runs:
>
> > "Some are immersed in contemplation of doctrine and faith
> >     Others stand stupefied between doubt and certainty
> >     Suddenly a Muezzin from his lurking-place cries out:
> >     O Fools! the Road [i.e., the "Mystic Road." or "Way of Salvation"] is neither here nor there."
>
> A curious parallel to this rubai occurs in Baba Tahir (IX. p. 86):
>
> > O Man who ne'er has studied Heavenly Lore,
> >     Nor set thy foot within Tavern Doors
> >     Thou knowest not what thou hast escaped or gained;
> >     How shalt thou come among the Elect? Alas!
>
> The poet wishes to conver that if a man has neither the self-denial of ascetism nor the courage of his contrary convictions he is not fit to be admitted among men of decided character.
>
> > All things come alike to all: there is one
> >     event to the righteous, and to the wicked;
> >     . . . to him that sacrificeth, and to him that
> >     sacrificeth not: as is the good, so is the
> >     sinner. - Ecclesiastes ix. 2.
>
> <sub>Taken from *The second edition of Edward FitzGerald's Rubáiyyát of 'Umar Khayyám.*, edited, with an introduction and notes by Edward Heron-Allen. London, Duckworth, 1908, with minor readability improvements by myself (nothing was excluded).
>
>   [Found here (open access)](https://www.omarkhayyamnederland.com/e-library/english/e-heron-allen---1898.html) - great website with a ton of versions of Rubaiyat, in different languages.</sub>

In "***Edward FitzGerald's Rubáiyát of Omar Khayyám***. With their original Persian sources collated from his own MSS., and literally translated by Edward Heron-Allen.", Heron-Allen provides what he thinks is the inspiration for the rubai in question:

> [image: An image of a passage that inspired the author]
>
> <sub>C refers to the Calcutta Manuscript. No. 1548
>   in the Bengal Asiatic Society's Library at Calcutta, containing 510 ruba'iyat. The original has been lost or stolen, but a copy has been made from the copy made for Edward FitzGerald at the instance of Prof. Cowell.</sub>

I was able to find an (allegedly) Persian text of this verse<sup>2</sup>:

[image: An image of the Persian translation of the passage written by the author]

with a more literal translation by Shahriar Shahriari:

> Some are thoughtful on their way
>   Some are doubtful, so they pray
>   I hear the hidden voice that may
>   Shout, "Both paths lead astray."

---

One illustrator depicts said muezzin as a sort of Grim Reaper, with the scythe and stuff.

[image: A black-and-white drawing of a man holding a scythe on top of a building]

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>: apparently, those guys may actually be translating different verses, since they cite different pages of the original manuscript. Now we'll never know ¯\_(ツ)_/¯</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>: [Found here](http://www.iranchamber.com/literature/khayyam/rubaiyat_khayyam3.php)</sub>

Comment: This is pretty darn impressive. +1 and accepted.